# How is Elon Musk's Tesla surviving in space?

Tags: vacuum, rocket-science, space-mission

I'm sorry I have to ask this question but I need evidence for a friend.  My answer to her that I trust people who specialize in the field to know better than me is 'BS' to her.

So to begin...
My friend believes the earth is flat.
She believes NASA is fake.
And now she thinks the Elon Musk Falcon Heavy launch wasn't real (well maybe the launch in the Earth's atmosphere) but the car in space was completely fake.
She wants me to research and provide evidence that it was real and a car can exist in space.
I know I know, many people say it's not worth the time but I truly care for  this person and have to see this through.  Plus if we're not trying to educate the world aren't we kind of being hypocritical? Yes? Haha ok here we go...

So the main point I'd need to have scientific evidence of is can the car exist in space.
Her points...

- a car would be destroyed in a vacuum
- elon says "you know it's real because it looks so fake"
- outgassing
- the car goes from a room into space
- did you see the photo of it from launch
- you know how much money it takes to “launch” something into space
- you think he just did that to have it “orbit for 1 billion years” that is literally so dumb it’s incomprehensible
- engineering teams never see the satellites launch ‘they just build them’
- look at the car - put the image in a photoshop editor - it’s worse than avatar special effects
- you think there are just cameras fixed to some car that’s literally just cruising around space and there’s not debris next to it from the
  rocket and there are no shots of the camera attachment from one side
  of the car to the other
- uber has 6000 engineers, they don’t know any of what uber is actually doing, they all do pieces of it, that isn’t even a valid
  argument, there’s only a portion of every business that knows
  anything, you think they send a brief to 6000 employees that they are
  going to do a launch
- next piece of evidence https://www.livescience.com/61690-why-spacex-roadster-looks-fake.html
  everyone thinks it looks fake, even elon, and his excuse is “the
  colors are more crisp in space”, and then people just believe that??
- you need to watch the footage again and wonder why there are articles upon articles explaining why “it looks fake”, when you don't
  think yourself it does
- I said I trust experts and asked who she trusts which she responded...no one, but that’s why i ask questions, to myself
  included, “do i think this looks real?” no, why?, “because of X Y and
  Z”, okay why is x this, research look, ask, repeat, always
- i expect this from you too - outgassing, photo editor images, see what has been previously launched
- look to see where the cameras are in the different angles
- instead of me asking you to research why it’s fake, you can instead tell me what you researched to show you it’s real, i will listen - i
  did this - your turn
- i don’t want any of the “trusting people” “watched it live” bull that’s not evidence, I’ll wait

[image]
[image]

- https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19690026573.pdf
- you can’t lose 1 billion a year, stock dropped 8.63% just last night, and then be spending millions to randomly launch a car into
  space. It doesn’t make sense - it’s a distraction to justify his lack
  of use with tax payer money

Have a field day ladies & gents ;) and if you could provide resources to anything that would possibly help educate and validate your answer I'd be moooore than appreciated.

Comment: Extraordinary claims necessitate extraordinary evidence. It should be *her* to provide experimental evidence for her claim, not you.

Comment: The live streaming  https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2018/2/6/16981144/spacex-tesla-falcon-heavy-roadster-live-stream

Comment: @valerio92 100% agree - but unfortunately, we live in a time of cultish ignorance. It isn't at all my duty but I'm taking it on as such.  This girl has asked me openly to provide evidence she'll take in (specifically about the cars materials and cameras).  In her mind she just saw a TV show by a scammer.  She's naive and young and unfortunately grew up with a family who shunned science.  I'm not trying to push anything down her throat just want to supply some concrete science she can choose to look more into.  Baby steps ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics

Comment: why fight on something so complicated and not on the simple numerous satellites around the earth? https://www.peakprosperity.com/blog/breaking-latest-satellite-imagery-fukushima/55711  they take photos of disaster areas around the globe? how can they stay up there if newton's theory does not work? etc.

Comment: @JohnRennie could you explain why the vacuum of space would not crush the materials a Tesla Roadster?  Would that not be a question of physics?

Comment: I appreciate what you’re trying to do, but reason is not the way to go. When logic goes against identity, logic always loses. Even if you “win” a debate, they’ll go back to believing what they did immediately afterward. This is like trying to logically convince someone to switch their sports team affiliation.

Comment: Just how is a Tesla fundamentally different from the Curiosity rover? Both are made from similar materials: steel and aluminium. Vacuum does not crush things. A balloon will expand until it bursts. A sealed can may not explode, just expand a bit, depending on its strength. A sheet of metal will stay exactly that: a sheet of metal.

Comment: The only way to convince somebody in this position is to befriend them and talk about literally anything else. In five years, if their friends are mostly science-believers like you, their identity may have changed a bit. You can have the debate then.

Comment: "*Plus if we're not trying to educate the world aren't we kind of being hypocritical?*" In that case, I would start with the Earth being flat claim...

Comment: Most points in this list are not claims and make no sense as arguments. What does "*outgassing*" mean? What is "*did you see the photo of it from launch*" doing on this list? Why is "*the car goes from a room into space*" an issue? How do you know that "*a car would be destroyed in a vacuum*"; satellites have no problem in space so why would a car be destroyed? A few of the points are interesting, but you can easily start form one end and ask her **why should that be an issue** and **what do you mean** in many of the cases.

Comment: *Plus if we're not trying to educate the world aren't we kind of being hypocritical? Yes?* No. The purpose of this site is not to educate the world. The purpose of this site is to provide answers to questions in the realm of mainstream physics. This flat Earth nonsense that has sprung up as of late is at the antipode of mainstream physics. And this is a late phenomenon. Almost every educated person in the west for the last 2000+ years has accepted a spherical Earth as a fact.  ...

Comment: ... The nonsense about Columbus convincing ignoramuses that the Earth is round is just that -- nonsense, from the late 19th century. Ferdinand and Isabel knew the Earth was round, as did all of their advisors. What Columbus believed (erroneously) was that the Earth was a lot smaller than everyone thought, and therefore he could sail east to India.

Comment: The sorry bunch who believe the Earth is flat are using that as a means to reject *all* of science. This conspiracy theory makes the "NASA faked the Moon landing" conspiracy theory very small in comparison. Assuming NASA did indeed fake the Moon landings, only a few tens of thousands of people were involved in that conspiracy. The number of  people involved in the round Earth conspiracy numbers in the tens to hundreds of million. The vast number of people involved alone is enough to debunk these conspiracy theories on the basis that "three can keep a secret if two of them are dead."

Comment: @DavidHammen you bring up some very valid points, thank you.  Looking back I agree it is not particularly hypocritical for this site specifically - but I do believe more sources need to step up to help educate the less fortunate who may be too intimidated to ask a question to a community this like.  For example - I think that if my friend happened to be searching for answers and see most of the responses I received across various forums she would've felt personally attacked, not seen evidence, and only strengthened her beliefs to protect herself...

Comment: ...I think experiencing a person who thought this way first hand (that I originally assumed barely existed), has made me believe that this bunch is not nearly as small as I had previously thought.  And the actual immediate scientific community may be smaller than thought - but simply have larger communities that support science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the burden of proof is on her, not you. She's the one who's going against consensus, so she's the one who actually needs to prove her points with evidence. But she probably won't listen to that, so let's refute her points, one by one, as concisely as possible:

- A car wouldn't actually be destroyed in a vacuum, especially not a convertible. The only way a vacuum would destroy an object is if it contained some pressurized gas and was dependent on atmospheric pressure to keep itself from blowing apart. Since we're dealing with a convertible electric car here (so no gas tank or air intake for the engine, either), there's no air anywhere except the tires. The tires are built to withstand substantial pressure anyway, and atmospheric pressure is only 15 psi. So if the tires were 15 psi below their absolute maximum rated pressure, then there's no reason they'd explode.
- Irrelevant. Elon Musk says stupid things.
- Outgassing is a process that occurs slowly, especially in cold environments. When I used to do a lot of vacuum testing, the only way you could make outgassing happen at any reasonable rate is by "baking out" the chamber at several hundred degrees, waiting a few days, and then coming back. In the cold vacuum of space, its effects are negligible over short time periods.
- That "room" was a capsule. If it wasn't in there, it would have been damaged by atmospheric friction on the way up. On top of that, the car's asymmetric shape would have messed up the rocket's aerodynamics in an unpredictable way, so it was easier and safer all around to place it in a capsule.
- Not sure what's being asked here.
- It takes a lot of money. Elon Musk also has a lot of money. He makes money through marketing stunts that make investors want to give him more money. This was one of those stunts.
- It was part marketing stunt, part "because he could." It's the same reason people climb Mount Everest, and they don't usually get much flak for that.
- As someone who is friends with a bunch of aerospace engineers, they absolutely do see the things that they built launch. That's most of the reason they're in the field they're in.
- No it isn't. You're just not used to photos where there's no atmosphere.
- The rocket staging was carefully planned so that debris would not hit anything. On top of that, anything that's jettisoned in the atmosphere is immediately slowed down by aerodynamic drag, to the point where it's not in any danger of hitting the car. As far as the camera attachment, there are several shots where you can see it. It's actually visible in the reflection from the door in the livestream at the moment.

[image]

- Yes, companies are big. But company-wide memos are also a thing.
- Photos in the absence of atmosphere really do look different. It's the same reason photos taken underwater look different.
- Just because it looks fake doesn't mean it is fake. Space is a strange place, after all.
- [Nothing to refute, seems to be the transcript of a conversation]
- See above.
- There are plenty of shots from the livestream, many of which are at different angles, and many of which show the different camera arms. There appear to be three cameras; one is built into the passenger seat, one is suspended on an arm off to the side, and one is suspended on an arm off to the front. The arm to the front is brilliantly lit up by this shot:

[image]

- Burden of proof is on her. That's how logic works. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.
- Everything I've laid down here is either basic physics that you can get from any textbook, or common sense.
- Microscopic etching only destroys things after a very long time, much longer than the timespan of the video. (Hence the word "microscopic".) Same with radiation damage - it's a worry when you want to build a space station that will last 20 years, but not when you're putting a car in space with some cameras until people stop watching.
- This is part marketing stunt. You have to spend money to make (people give you) money; and as long as he can keep convincing investors to give him money, then it really doesn't matter how much money his companies lose. You should definitely ask for a source on that "taxpayer money" claim.

Comment: +1, if nothing else for the thoroughly enjoyable writing style: I had quite a few chuckles. The simple explantion: this whole thing is utterly easey-peasey compared with what most launches do. I find it quite comical that Musk uses a one tonne automobile as payload to show off a heavy lifting rocket's capabilities: the phrase damnation through faint praise springs to mind. I would have thought a fifty tonne teapot with a portrait of Bertrand Russell on it would have been far more appropriate. And with huge retroreflectors on it so we can always find it again. That's what I would have done.